# Entity Framework Oracle connection

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I use entity framework but I can not connect to the oracle database

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
public class EShopContext :DbContext
{
    public EShopContext(bool oracle) : base(new OracleConnection("User Id=ETICARET;Password=medoc; DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.202)(PORT=1522))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER =192.168.1.202)(SID=XE)))"),true)
    {

    }
    public EShopContext() : base("Server=.;Database=ETicaret;User Id=sa;Password=a93c85y85") //sql connection String
    {

    }
    public virtual DbSet<Admin> Admins { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        using (var context = new EShopContext(true))
        {
            try
            {
                context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

    }
```

---

```
context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
```

throw exception => {"An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the failure."}

Comment: Do you use Devart, an oracle client or directly the oracle dlls in your project?

Comment: I used Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client referance

Comment: If your connection string is real, after finding your question's answer, change oracle login user id and password. When asking question change real information to fake then write here.

Comment: ı have oracle client  but  I didn't use Devart

Comment: thanks Jahed Kabiri this is fake connection. this is test connection

Comment: Regarding the exception. I have found with such exceptions that there are often Inner Exceptions, nested several levels deep. The innermost exception usually has the most meaningful error message. Are there any inner exceptions in your case?

Comment: Please provide the full error stack.

Comment: You cannot connect with the sa user, create an another account.

Comment: @cSteusloff  sql connection is working but oracle connection is not working an I m not using sa user oracle db connection